# Synchronization at multiple level java behavior

Tags: java, synchronization

As shown in example below, once lock is taken on an object in `call` method, there is no need for further methods to have `synchronized` keyword.

```
public class Prac
 { 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      new Prac().call();
    }

    private synchronized void call()
    {
      further();
    }

    private synchronized void further()
    {
      oneMore();
    }

    private synchronized void oneMore()
    {
      // do something
    }
 }
```

But, if I still add `synchronized` keyword to `further` and `onceMore`, what java does on such encounters? Does java checks if lock is required or not? or as method call is in same stack, it just proceeds without checking if lock is required or not as lock is already acquired.

**Note** : My doubt is how java will behave in such situation, I am not sure, but I think it is different from biased locking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact,  java checks if the current thread has the lock every time it enters a synchronized method.

```
private synchronized void oneMore()
    {
      // do something
    }
```

This is equivalent to

```
private void oneMore(){
      synchronized(this){
      // do something
    }
}
```

But because of the fact that intrinsic locks in java are reentrant; if a thread has the lock, it doesn't reacquire it once it enters another synchronized block as in you example. Otherwise, this will create a deadlock.

Update: To answer your comment below. From Java Concurency in practice:

```
Reentrancy is implemented by associating with each lock an acquisition count 
and an owning thread. When the count is zero, the lock is considered unheld. 
When a thread acquires a previously unheld lock, the JVM records the owner 
and sets the acquisition count to one. If that same thread acquires the lock 
again, the count is incremented, and when the owning thread exits the
synchronized block, the count is decremented. When the count reaches zero, 
the lock is released.
```

Therefore, checking if a lock is acquired, is equivalent to an if statement (more or less) that the variable holding the owning thread is equal or not to the thread trying to acquire the lock.

However, as you pointed out, there is no need for the synchronized keyword on the private methods. In general, you should try to remove unnecessary synchronization since that usually leads to degraded performance.